# Mesh shows in other tabs but doesn't in "Layout"

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm having a problem where a sword is not showing in the layout but is showing in other tabs, the everything in layout are visible and I can't seem to find the solution.

Layout Tab:
[image]

Modelling Tab:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Layout tab, you're in [Local View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/local_view.html). You can switch to Global View with <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> or via the menu : *View/Local View/Toggle Local View*.